# Gas.water tank issue with flame control

Tags: water-heater, pilot-light, gas-burner

As soon as I turn on the burner it lights up fine for about 5 seconds then turns off like its running out of gas and after I try to re light the pilot it takes about 5 mins to get the pilot back on.

The water tank model is 42V-50 at 11/2004 The controller is: Robertshaw 110-326 It's hard to put pilot aa I said wait for 5 min t0 10.min. I did a test turn pilot and it was last for 10 to 15 min then went out. The exhaust is fine as I feel a drift, also it was same configuration for last 2 years. All storage room is never been changed. I can buy a new heater for 1700 with install but I wanted to try to fix it, I did not wanted to thru away because on controller. I cleaned the thermocouple near burner not helped

Comment: Make/model? How old? Any other gas appliances and, if so, do they work properly?

Comment: It would also be helpful to [edit] to fix up all the typos. Some can be read around, some are really confusing.

Comment: Lets wait for @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact since he has all the info now

Comment: @FreeMan it would be helpful if you just go ahed and fix the spelling, since you already know what it is rather than telling others what to do

Comment: Is 11/2004 installation date? If so 19 years old may seriously be worth considering replacement.

Comment: replace.aa.thermocouple you.probably.fix.t0 issue

Comment: I usually do, @asinine, though I've given up on yours. However, as noted, there are some where I have no idea what the OP is trying to say.

Comment: @asinine I'm no water heater expert. But sometimes the model # can help (e.g., by finding manuals or known specific issues) and it also helps a real expert. So no, just giving me the model # that I asked for doesn't mean I have all the answers.

Comment: @FreeMan sorry to hear that, at least I tried to fix some, but my spelling sucks as you noticed, however to my excuse this is not a spelling/grammar web site. I always consider that English is not the OP mother language, so asking in demanding tone to fix the spelling is just a insult.

Comment: So no solution ? I ordered the gas flow control. Not sure it can fix.